# Faced Error or Error Faced

Tags: phrases, shorthand

I want to make the following sentence short by removing **we**. Please help me which one is correct form.

> The error we faced is "Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum allowed databases."

Option 1 : The error faced is "Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum allowed databases"

Option 2 : The faced error is "Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum allowed databases"

Please let me know which one is correct, or if both of them are correct provide some references for further study.

Thank you:)

Comment: Both sound clumsy. Option 1 (error faced) less so.

Comment: Both sound clumsy because *faced* has no business being in that sentence in the first place. "The error is X" is all anybody could possibly need. And lo and behold, it helps you with your actual task of making the sentence shorter, too.

Comment: Since you're actually talking about an error message, and not an error per se, I would reword the sentence this way: "The error message reads, "Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum allowed databases."

Answer (score 1):

Neither are particularly spectacular and the other answers and comments offer descent suggestions for improvement. But if you are *really* attached to "faced" the appropriate way to say this would be:

> The error faced **was** "Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum allowed databases."

"Faced error" isn't strictly an error but it doesn't read quite as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "The error we saw was" or even easier "The error was".

Answer (score 0):

"Sorry, .....databases" was displayed.

Of course it is a mistake, and the message appeared in front of you.